# how to convert this datetime format into unix timestamp

Tags: android, date, time

I tried to parse this date `2017-03-04**T**17:20:55Z` to Unix timestamp and I received a parse error for the T char (bolded it).

I tried to use new SimpleDateFormat and DateTimeFormatter. How can I get a Unix timestamp from this DateTime format?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post your code.

Comment: Try changing the input to `2017-03-04T17:20:55Z`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes to escape characters in the format string of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2017-03-04T17:20:55Z");
```